# How do I add a custom entry to the Fedora grub2 boot menu, as legacy (not UEFI)?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, fedora, grub2

Yesterday, I installed Fedora 25 on my Windows 10 system to dual boot. Unfortunately, I quickly figured out that the computer would no longer boot to Windows off the boot menu, though it does have a 'Windows' option on the boot menu that boots to recovery.

I think what happened is that Grub2 found the Windows Recovery partition and labeled that "Windows", so every time I try to boot to Windows I end up in Windows recovery.

If I run `sudo fdisk -l`, here's what I get:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x568c8dd9

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 310306815 309280768 147.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       310306816 312403967   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       312403968 500117503 187713536  89.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       312406016 500117503 187711488  89.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-d2b4044e-3d8d-485c-8ee9-7c197f600aa6: 89.5 GiB, 96106184704 bytes, 187707392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.6 GiB, 8162115584 bytes, 15941632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 31.9 GiB, 34254880768 bytes, 66904064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Notice how there are two MS-DOS partitions based on the HTFS/NTFS/exFAT format, `sda1` and `sda2`, with `sda1` being 500MB in size and `sda2` being 147.5GB in size, the same size my Windows partition should be. I'm assuming the 500MB partition is the recovery partition, and the boot flag on that partition explains why it is booting into recovery instead of Windows 10.

I can only assume that I now need to add the proper Windows partition to Grub2 if I want to be able to boot to it, but after hours of googling it seems there just isn't any documentation I can find on adding new Grub2 entries on a *recent* version of Fedora in Legacy instead of UEFI. Does anyone know how you'd do this?

Comment: Have you made sure to do ```grub-update``` (or grub2 equivalent) to see if grub can find your windows partitions?

Comment: @tealkine repeatedly. It only ever finds the one, sda1.